# LDAP unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed

Tags: ldap

I set a centos 8 server as openldap server and kerberos auth. and I'm not able to get userldap remotely

#server:

```
[15:04 root@server ~] > ldapsearch -x -b "dc=bravo,dc=lab" -H ldap:/// -D "cn=admin,dc=bravo,dc=lab" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=bravo,dc=lab> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# bravo.lab
dn: dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
objectClass: top
o: bravo
dc: bravo

# groups, bravo.lab
dn: ou=groups,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: groups

# people, bravo.lab
dn: ou=people,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: people

# kb_user01, people, bravo.lab
dn: uid=kb_user01,ou=people,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: kb_user01
cn: John
sn: Doe
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/kb_user01
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9S3hGUnozUnUzTVMxZXQvNDVLdFFYSHVWVU4vajV1MVI=

# kb_user01, groups, bravo.lab
dn: cn=kb_user01,ou=groups,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: kb_user01
gidNumber: 10000
memberUid: kb_user01

# kb_user02, people, bravo.lab
dn: uid=kb_user02,ou=people,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: kb_user02
cn: Adam
sn: blanc
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 10001
gidNumber: 10001
homeDirectory: /home/kb_user02
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9SUFrSkUvQmZObHdlSmpUblFaMWxjMWRMR1k3MFh5Nlg=

# kb_user02, groups, bravo.lab
dn: cn=kb_user02,ou=groups,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: kb_user02
gidNumber: 10001
memberUid: kb_user02

# system, bravo.lab
dn: ou=system,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: system

# readonly, system, bravo.lab
dn: cn=readonly,ou=system,dc=bravo,dc=lab
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
cn: readonly
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9M3lSV2wzdkhpc0UzR2w3d3JqMDR4dTF6R3NDajB3Rm4g
description: Bind DN user for LDAP Operations

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 10
enter code here`# numEntries: 9
```

I created user readonly to query ldapDatabase with those Access

```
[15:16 root@server ~] > ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(olcDatabase={1}mdb)' olcAccess
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=admin,ou=People
 ,dc=bravo,dc=lab" write by dn="cn=readonly,ou=People,dc=bravo,dc=lab" read by
  self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=admin,ou=People,dc=bravo,dc=lab" write by dn="cn=
 readonly,ou=People,dc=bravo,dc=lab" read by self write by anonymous auth by *
  none
```

client nslcd configuration

```
uri ldap://server.bravo.lab/
base dc=bravo,dc=lab
binddn cn=readonly,ou=People,dc=bravo,dc=lab
```

When i launch this it does not work

```
id kb_user01
```

I get on the server

```
Oct  7 15:26:28 server slapd[114988]: conn=1312 fd=17 ACCEPT from IP=10.0.0.111:48728 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Oct  7 15:26:28 server slapd[114988]: conn=1312 op=0 BIND dn="cn=readonly,ou=People,dc=bravo,dc=lab" method=128
Oct  7 15:26:28 server slapd[114988]: conn=1312 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=53 text=unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed
Oct  7 15:26:28 server slapd[114988]: conn=1312 op=1 UNBIND
Oct  7 15:26:28 server slapd[114988]: conn=1312 fd=17 closed
```

Do you have any Idea because from my point of view I would like to grant read access without password but still i get the error.

Please help thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it,

I did three mistakes:

1 : On the client side (nslcd configuration) the right Binddn was

```
binddn cn=readonly,ou=***SYSTEM***,dc=bravo,dc=lab
```

2 : On the client side (nslcd configuration) in BindPW I put the Hashed password instant of clair on

3 : the same mistake as #1 but this time on ACL of the ldap

```
by dn="cn=readonly,ou=***SYSTEM***,dc=bravo,dc=lab" read by self write
```